# Comparing high dimensional samples

Tags: distributions, multiple-comparisons, conv-neural-network, high-dimensional

I am working on a project with Convolutional Neural Networks and their internal representation of the classes on the "feature space" (aka. the flatten layer at the end of all the convolution and pooling). More precisely, I end up with 512-d vector representation of the images.
My goal is to compare the class-distributions generated by different architectures and see if something interesting emerges. The idea is to compare the same class across architectures as well as the differences between classes.

So far I have thought of:

- Compare mean vector and covariance matrix of each class, across different architectures.
- Distance between means of classes
- Compare average cosine similarity between images of the same class.
- Maybe do some dimensionality reduction to use conventional tests, but I think most of the information would be lost in such a reduction.

Are there better approaches that come to your mind? Tests for high dimensional data? Or do you find shortcomings in my ideas?

Thank you a lot in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Even for a given architecture, there’s no reason that two separate fittings of the model will make things comparable. **Representation learning** is hard. As an analogy, if you’re learning word embeddings, any rotation or reflection of these is equivalent, but you’ll find low similarity between means in the original and the rotation.

Comment: Are you referring to same-class comparisons? Like class cat in architecture $A_i$ will not necessarily be similar to class cat in the rest of the representations $A_j, j \neq i$?